# My C# ListView Compare Function is too slow

Tags: c#

I am trying to sort a `ListView` which also has a `DateTime` column. This is the code I use:

```
public bool isDate(Object obj)
{
    string strDate = obj.ToString();
    try
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
        if (dt != DateTime.MinValue && dt != DateTime.MaxValue)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public int Compare(object o1, object o2)
{
    if (!(o1 is ListViewItem))
        return (0);
    if (!(o2 is ListViewItem))
        return (0);

    ListViewItem lvi1 = (ListViewItem)o2;
    string str1 = lvi1.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;
    ListViewItem lvi2 = (ListViewItem)o1;
    string str2 = lvi2.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;

    int result;
    if (lvi1.ListView.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
    {
        if (isDate(str1) && isDate(str2))
            result = DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Parse(str1), DateTime.Parse(str2));
        else
            result = String.Compare(str1, str2);
    }
    else
        result = String.Compare(str2, str1);

    LastSort = ByColumn;
    return result;
}
```

The `ListView` holds about 2000 entries and the problem is that it's very slow. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:** Thank you very much. I am new to this and here is my code now. It is much faster and I fixed my logic.

```
public int Compare(object o1, object o2)
{
    var lvi1 = o2 as ListViewItem;
    var lvi2 = o1 as ListViewItem;
    if (lvi1 == null || lvi2 == null)
        return 0;

    string str1 = lvi1.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;
    string str2 = lvi2.SubItems[ByColumn].Text;

    int result;
    DateTime dateValue1 = new DateTime();
    DateTime dateValue2 = new DateTime();

    if (lvi1.ListView.Sorting == SortOrder.Ascending)
    {  
        if (DateTime.TryParse(str1, out dateValue1) && DateTime.TryParse(str2, out dateValue2)) 
            result = DateTime.Compare(dateValue1, dateValue2);
        else
            result = String.Compare(str1, str2);
    }
    else
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParse(str1, out dateValue1) && DateTime.TryParse(str2, out dateValue2))
            result = DateTime.Compare(dateValue2, dateValue1);
        else
            result = String.Compare(str2, str1);
    }

    LastSort = ByColumn;
    return result;  
}
```

Comment: Is this using WPF? If so, could you tag it as such?

Comment: Why aren't you using `DateTime.TryParse()` instead of catching a parsing exception?  It returns a `bool` and uses an output parameter to set the value if it succeeds.

Comment: Also I think there is something wrong with your logic, when sort order is ascending you care about DateTime fields, but in other case (descending) you aren't care about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some optimization comes in my mind:

1. Instead of isDate use:`DateTime.TryParse`
2. Instead of doing two time casting:

   `if (!(o1 is ListViewItem)) return (0);`

   `ListViewItem lvi1 = (ListViewItem)o2;`

use one time casting:

```
var lvi1 = o2 as ListViewItem;
if (lvi1 == null)
   return 0;
```

Also I suggest check your code logic (as I mentioned in comment).

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to TryParse and I think I fixed the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just set your ListViewItem.Tag to the DateTime? Then when comparing the DateTimes:

```
DateTime d = (DateTime)ListViewItem.Tag;
```

Comment: I agree with this suggestion, this would avoid all conversions from string to `DateTime` that are ocurring twice (inside isDate(), and then when comparing both DateTime values inside `Compare()`. If `Tag` is null then you still can fallback to string comparison like your original logic is doing.